# Android-Gradle: Remote repo+ variant-aware dependency resolution

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

According to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html the new Android Gradle Plugin has a variant-aware dependency resolution:

> Android plugin 3.0.0 and higher include a new dependency mechanism that automatically matches variants when consuming a library. This means an app's debug variant automatically consumes a library's debug variant, and so on. It also works when using flavors—an app's freeDebug variant will consume a library's freeDebug variant.

But the examples are all written for local project dependencies.

```
implementation project(':library')
```

***How does this mechanism work for remote dependencies, loaded from a maven repository for example?***

```
implementation 'com.example.android:library:0.0.1'
```

Furthermore, I figured out two more problems:

1. How to publish all configurations of an android library together to a maven repository?

At the moment, we are publishing with

```
publishing {
  ...
  artifact(output.outputFile) {
      builtBy variant.assemble
  };
  pom.withXml {
    ...
    dependencyNode.appendNode('scope', configurationName.contains("mplementation") ? "runtime" : "compile")
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

2. It seems that the property `<scope>runtime</scope>` in our *.pom suggested for implementation-dependencies is completely ignored by the android-gradle plugin?

Although, we have a `<scope>runtime</scope>`, we still can use the classes from the transitive dependent library at compile-time in our project.